# XEP-0235: OAuth Over XMPP implementation

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I am making a chat app with Operfire server using Smack API. I want to implement the **XEP-0235: OAuth Over XMPP** or **token based reconnection** in my app. The doc is not giving much information, searched a lot but I did not get any answer.

How can I implement the extension?

I read **XEP-xxxx: Token-based reconnection** doc, U send the following iq packet as mention in extension.

```
<iq to='domain@example.com' id='60fG0-45' type='get'><query xmlns='erlang-solutions.com:xmpp:token-auth:0'</query></iq>
```

but not receiving any response from server.

I found a plugin  on  https://github.com/rxwen/openfire-oauth-auth-provider
but I don't know how to use it or is it what am I searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding XEP-0235: OAuth Over XMPP

The document contains WARNING in start as:

WARNING: This document has been automatically Deferred after 12 months of inactivity in its previous Experimental state. Implementation of the protocol described herein is not recommended for production systems. However, exploratory implementations are encouraged to resume the standards process.

The document of XEP-xxxx: Token-based reconnection contains WARNING as:

WARNING: This document has not yet been accepted for consideration or approved in any official manner by the XMPP Standards Foundation, and this document is not yet an XMPP Extension Protocol (XEP). If this document is accepted as a XEP by the XMPP Council, it will be published at http://xmpp.org/extensions/ and announced on the  mailing list.

So it's clear that you will not find any such functionality in Openfire Server and also there are very rare chances to find some plugin implementing any of these XEP's.

Also for such requirements, it requires changes on both Server and Client ends which means Openfire Server and Smack library for Android both will have to implement it.